# Definition: $a \prec b$ , $ a \npreceq b$ , $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, definition, real-numbers

let be $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$:

$a \prec b$ if $a \preceq b \wedge a \neq b$

$a \npreceq b $ if $b \prec a$

is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $a\npreceq b$ means that $a\preceq b$  is not true. $b\prec a$ is equivalent if and only if the order is a *total* (linear) order (wich is the case in $\mathbf R$ ordered on its usual way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. For more information check [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aStrictly_Precede) website